# Recursive procedure to tail-recursive procedure

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I am trying to construct a tail-recursive procedure out of another procedure I already have constructed. But I am not fully aware of how I am supposed to think. I give you two examples where the first one is my procedure which isn't tail recursive and the second is my "attempt" to make a tail-recursive procedure. Yeah... attempt :) I would be happy for any advice of how to construct tail recursive procedures, how I should start, think and whatsoever.

Edit: The first one works exactly as I want. `(define square (lambda (x) (* x x)))`

`(do-to-each square '(1 2 3))` should square every number, that is make the list `(1 4 9)`

---

```
(define do-to-each
  (lambda (proc lst)
    (if (list-empty? lst)
        (list-create)
          (list-insert (proc (list-first lst)) (do-to-each proc (list-rest lst))))))

(define do-to-each-tail
  (lambda (proc lst)
    (define loop
      (lambda (n result)
        (if (= n 1)
            (list result)
            (if (eq? (length result) 1)
                (car result)
                (loop (- n 1) (cons (car result) (do-to-each-tail proc (cdr result))))))))
    (loop (length lst) lst)))
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27386520/124319

Comment: Ah thank you, gonna take a look at that. :)

Comment: The easiest way to work from the tail of the list, the result ends up in reverse, and then you simply reverse the result again when you return it in the base case.

Comment: In my experience, whenever I type "length", I know I'm on the wrong track and start over.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to keep track of lengths, indexes, etc., as we can write a tail-recursive solution iterating directly over the input list, accumulating the result and (just to preserve order) reverse the result at the end.

For example, using your notation for list operations, this is how a possible solution looks like - and notice how we call the looping helper procedure with an initial value for the accumulated result, and after that we `reverse` the output:

```
(define do-to-each-tail
  (lambda (proc lst)
    (define loop
      (lambda (lst result)
        (if (list-empty? lst)
            result
            (loop (list-rest lst)
                  (list-insert (proc (list-first lst)) result)))))
    (reverse (loop lst (list-create)))))
```

It works as expected:

```
(do-to-each-tail square '(1 2 3))
=> '(1 4 9)
```